# NDB transaction CannotAcquireLockException Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-transactions, mysql-cluster

I'm using a MySQL NDB cluster with master-master architecture. My understanding is that if I search after some data non-id based this will hit all NDB nodes. If one node can't acquire the lock because the row is locked by another transaction and the wait time elapsed I will get a "Lock wait timeout" exception.

The application that connects to this DB is standard spring boot with hibernate(database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
database: MYSQL)

There are some transactions that are read-only. The transaction performing the read is good with before or after values (relative to other transaction). According to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-excerpt/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-limitations-transactions.html)  if I don't add "LOCK IN SHARE MODE." this will happen naturally.

My method is annotated with: `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`
Is there something else I should do to make sure my application just reads without waiting or blocking another transaction?